# Same crash produces different stack traces depending on the device

Tags: android, stack-trace

I have an app on Google Play that is suffering from a crash called by a null pointer exception. When viewing the stack traces of the crash on the Google Play Developer Console, even if the Android version is the same, the line numbers the stack trace reports are different depending on the device.  Since this is Android SDK code, and it is the same version of Android, **why are the line numbers not identical?**

I have a couple guesses: 1.) The Google Developer Console reports these devices as Android 4.4, but it is possible they have different 4.4.x versions. 2.) These are different devices so manufactures have changed some code in the SDK to account for each specific device.

All help is greatly appreciated, example stack traces copied below.

This stack trace is from a Samsung device running Android 4.4:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.richardlucasapps.netlive.MainService: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2830)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:174)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1389)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
>   at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:38)
>   at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)

This one is from a different device, but it is running Android 4.4 as well:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.richardlucasapps.netlive.MainService: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:138)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5111)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
>   at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:38)
>   at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks about the same to me, see this common line,
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:38) at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)`

Somewhere in your `MainService` class, it appears you are attempting to convert a null Array to a List.
Lets confirm by looking at the [code for Arrays.asList](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Arrays.java#154):

```
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... array) {
        return new ArrayList<T>(array);
    }
```

Ok, so this calls a constructor which is [also in Arrays.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Arrays.java#36https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Arrays.java#36):

```
    ...
    ArrayList(E[] storage) {
        if (storage == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("storage == null");
        }
        a = storage;
    }
    ...
```

this is where the `storage == null` comics from.  My advice,  check for null Array usage in your app.

> why are the line numbers not identical?

Those lines that differ relate to the android framework, and in this particular situation, how it starts up your service which in turn finds an Null Pointer during start up and fails. Starting a service can vary from device to device depending on the manufacturer and the API level.

Comment: thank you for your help. I understand what is causing the crash, my question was related to why the stack traces were different. If you look closely, the line numbers are different for each stack trace, and I want to know why this is.

Comment: @Richard,  those lines that differ relate to the android framework and how it starts up your service which in turns finds an NPE during start up and fails. Starting a service can vary from device to device depending on the manufacturer and the API level.

Comment: Got it, that is what I thought may be the case. Can you please add this to your answer so I can accept it? Thank you.